# Has anyone found that REGEX "\b" doesn't work in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Has anyone found that REGEX "\b" doesn't work in MYSQL?

I have a nice piece of regex that matches well using regex engines

```
^(//)?w7\b
```

But when I use it as part of a MYSQL query

```
WHERE ( e.department REGEXP '^(//)?w7\b' )
```

it will not match.  If I remove the \b component, the match works well but its not to the accuracy that I need with the \b (basicly I need to match the whole word W7 only)

Thank you!

Comment: MySQL uses [POSIX like regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions), see the MySQL manual for [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For MySQL versions prior to MySQL 8.0.4, the [`REGEXP` (MySQL 5.6 ref)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html) docs indicate that the start-of-word/end-of-word markers are:

```
[[:<:]], [[:>:]]
```

> These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and end of words, respectively.

Try:

```
WHERE ( e.department REGEXP '^(//)?w7[[:>:]]' )
```

[After 8.0.4](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-compatibility), `\b` is used for word boundary instead.

Comment: It may well have said that in earlier versions of MySQL, but your link now takes me to the 8.0 documentation that does _not_ explicitly say that earlier versions didn't use \b word markers. It says "_The Spencer library supports word-beginning and word-end boundary markers ([[:<:]] and [[:>:]] notation). ICU does not. For ICU, you can use \b to match word boundaries;_", so the current library explicitly does not allow the old word markers, but it doesn't explicitly say that the old library doesn't permit \b.

Comment: @Auspex: updated. Docs don't usually exhaustively list what they don't support, would be a lot of wasted paper.

Comment: Absolutely. However my reading of the 8.0 doc left me thinking that _either_ form was valid in the older versions, which is why i thought i needed to comment.