# Find the right Regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex, categories

I have this kind of categories : 
Main Categories (cat) :

- 1
- 2
- ..
- 15

Sub Cat example :

For Main Cat 1 :

- 1.1.2
- 1.1.3
- 1.2
- 1.11.2

For Main Cat 2 :

- 2.1.2
- 2.1.2.4
- 2.12.4

For Main Cat 15 :

- 15.11.12

**I would like to find a regex for MYSQL that find categories that begin by a category**.

For example (with example above) :

---

Find categories begin by **1**
 should Return :

1.1.2

1.1.3

1.2

1.11.2

If i do my Regex I will have  that :

1.1.2

1.1.3

1.2

1.11.2

**15.11.12**

(I don't want that)

---

Find categories begin by **1.1**
 should Return :

1.1.2

1.1.3

If i do my Regex I will have  that :

1.1.2

1.1.3

**1.11.2**

(I don't want that)

---

Find categories begin by **2.1**
 should Return :

2.1.2

2.1.2.4

If i do my Regex I will have  that :

2.1.2

2.1.2.4

**2.12.4**

(I don't want that)

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Sound like you need to use the `\b`

Comment: I am wondering what exactly are you using for your RegEXP - php or sql. They do have different synthax. I am also wondering to which synthax `\b` relates. I coun't find a reference in 5 mins for `SQL(actually MySQL)` synthax, but i know it's a perfectly valid `Php  synthax`

Comment: Thank you, I'm using mysql for the regex. I will check the \b. I found this for \b :  
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403104/has-anyone-found-that-regex-b-doesnt-work-in-mysql ]
)
but i don't how my Regex should look like

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a regex at all and might be over complicating it.

If you know which category you want to look for, assuming the user is requesting the section "1.1" or the section "1.2" or "1.4.1" then you could search using a wildcard.

You don't mention if this data is being stored as a decimal or a varchar so I'm guessing it's a varchar and only because, in most database I've ever seen they always get stored as that.

So if the category was 1.1 and you wanted 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.12 etc you would just search for anything that matched 1.1.% which means to search for anything that is 1.1 followed by a dot and not followed directly by a number.

Query example:

```
$category = "1.1";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [your_table] WHERE cat LIKE '".$category.".%'";
```

This query would match:

```
1.1.0
1.1.1
1.1.15
// Any anything else starting with 1.1.
```

Comment: Thank you,
I feel stupid that i didn't think about this simple query... this is faster than Regex ?

Comment: @AdamWhateverson - "Find categories begin by 1.1 should Return" does not include "1.1".  Please add it, or clarify that it is deliberately excluded.  The other Answers are either slow or incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL prior to 8.0.4, You can use the end of word boundary marker ([`[[:>:]]`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax)) in a regexp to avoid selecting sub-categories beginning with e.g. `2.12` when you are searching for `2.1`. Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE category RLIKE '^2.1[[:>:]]'
```

For MySQL 8.0.4 and later, it supports `\b` as a word boundary, and you can use this instead (note the need to duplicate the `\` as MySQL interprets it as an escape character inside strings):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE category RLIKE '^2.1\\b'
```

Answer (score 0):

For Main Category 1:  `LIKE '1.%'`
For Main Category 15:  `LIKE '15.%'`
For Category 2.1:  `LIKE '2.1.%'`

Furthermore, by using `LIKE` you can make use of `INDEX(cat)` to improve performance.

*But...* This may not be sufficient.  (And I claim that the Question was ambiguous here.)  If there could be an entry with just `'2.1'` (without a sub-sub-cat), then those LIKEs are inadequate.  So...

Plan A:  `col REGEXP '^2[.]1([.]|$)'` -- But `REGEXP` won't use any index.

Plan B:  `col = '2.1' OR col LIKE '2.1.%'  -- But`OR` prevents using index.

Plan C:  Clumsy, but the fastest for large datasets (due to the index):

```
    WHERE col LIKE '2.1%'             -- uses INDEX(col) for quick filtering
      AND col REGEXP '^2[.]1([.]|$)'  -- avoids "2.15" and other things
```

Why the brackets around `.`?:

- `.` by itself matches any one character  -- don't want that
- `[.]` matches any of the set of characters including just a period
- `\.` matches a period, but, depending on context, you might need 1 or 2 or 4 backslashes.

Bottom line:  For simplicity, use Plan B.  For Performance, use Plan C.